# iOS 13 get application statusBar crash

Tags: objective-c, ios13

only crash on beta2 and beta 3 when call code like this,:

```
[application valueForKeyPath:@"statusBar"]
```

some can help me? i call this method to get phone's network status.
the whole code like this:

```c
if (![self isIPhoneX]) {
        if ([[application valueForKeyPath:@"_statusBar"] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBar_Modern")]) {
            children = [[[[application valueForKeyPath:@"_statusBar"] valueForKeyPath:@"_statusBar"] valueForKeyPath:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
        } else {
            children = [[[application valueForKeyPath:@"_statusBar"] valueForKeyPath:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
        }
        Class expectClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView");
        for (id child in children) {
            if ([child isKindOfClass:expectClass]) {
                int netType = [[child valueForKeyPath:@"dataNetworkType"] intValue];
                switch (netType) {
                    case 0: state  = @"";break;
                    case 1: state  = @"2g";break;
                    case 2: state  = @"3g";break;
                    case 3: state  = @"4g";break;
                    case 5: state  = @"wifi";break;
                    default: state = @"";break;
                } /* switch */
            }
        }
    } else {
        id statusBar = [application valueForKeyPath:@"statusBar"];
        id statusBarView = [statusBar valueForKeyPath:@"statusBar"];
        UIView *foregroundView = [statusBarView valueForKeyPath:@"foregroundView"];
        children = [[foregroundView subviews][2] subviews];
        for (id child in children) {
            if ([child isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIStatusBarWifiSignalView")]) {
                state  = @"wifi";  
            }else if ([child isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIStatusBarStringView")]) {
                NSString *str = [child valueForKeyPath:@"_originalText"]; 
                if ([str isEqualToString:@"4G"]) {
                    state  = @"4g";  
                }else if([str isEqualToString:@"3G"]){
                    state  = @"3g"; 
                } else{
                    state  = @"2g"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I install iOS 13 open beta version and every thing runs good except some label showing ...,but i receive crash when online beta2 and beta3 version.

Comment: What you are doing is not valid and has never been valid. Never dig into the private subview structure. Such code is always fragile and it can break during any iOS update. Only use provided public APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString *)deviceNetworkingType
{
    NSString *strNetworkInfo = @"No Network";
    struct sockaddr_storage zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress,sizeof(zeroAddress)); zeroAddress.ss_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.ss_family = AF_INET;
    // Recover reachability flags
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL,(struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability,&flags);
    CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);
    if(!didRetrieveFlags){ return strNetworkInfo;}
    BOOL isReachable = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)!=0);
    BOOL needsConnection = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)!=0);
    if(!isReachable || needsConnection) {return strNetworkInfo;}
    if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired)== 0){
        strNetworkInfo = @"WIFI";
    }
    if(((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnDemand ) != 0) ||(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnTraffic) != 0) {
        if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsInterventionRequired) == 0){
            strNetworkInfo = @"WIFI";
        }
    }
    if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) ==kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
            CTTelephonyNetworkInfo * info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
            NSString *currentRadioAccessTechnology = info.currentRadioAccessTechnology;
            if (currentRadioAccessTechnology) {
                if ([currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
                    strNetworkInfo =@"4G";
                } else if ([currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge] || [currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
                    strNetworkInfo =@"2G";
                } else {
                    strNetworkInfo =@"3G";
                }
            }
        } else {
            if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) == kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) {
                if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection) == kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection) {
                    if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired) == kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired) {
                        strNetworkInfo =@"2G";
                    } else {
                        strNetworkInfo =@"3G";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return strNetworkInfo;
}
```